# How to keep group column in each tibble and rename them?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the follow `list-column` called `my$data`:

```
library(tidyverse)

dataset<-data.frame(matrix(rnorm(6*30,1000,100),ncol=6))
cluster<-kmeans(dataset,centers=3)
dataset$kmeans<-as.factor(cluster[['cluster']])

my<-dataset%>%
  group_by(kmeans)%>%
  nest()
```

I have two doubts:

- how to keep `kmeans` column in each `tibble` into a list-column?
- how to rename the `tibble`s into a list-column (ex. *6 variables* to `data1`, `data2` and `data3`)?

With `base::split` function, the group column is preserved. Example:

```
mylist<-split(dataset,dataset$kmeans)
```

And `base::names` function:

```
names(mylist)<-paste0('data',seq_along(mylist))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is possible to have the grouped column in `nest` however, an alternative is to create a copy of the column and then use `nest`.

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata <- dataset %>%
              mutate(new_kmean = kmeans) %>%
              group_by(kmeans) %>%
              nest()

names(mydata$data) <- paste0('data',seq_along(mydata$data))


mydata$data

#$data1
# A tibble: 16 x 7
#    X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6 new_kmean
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>    
# 1  952. 1057. 1037. 1049.  871. 1103. 3        
# 2 1042.  986. 1027.  982.  836. 1121. 3        
# 3  990.  996. 1121. 1134.  998. 1098. 3 
#....
```

Comment: Rename  *tibbles*, not the columns. Example: *6 variables* to `data1`.

Comment: @user108927 sorry, I didn't read the question properly. To rename tibbles what's wrong with your current approach? It seems to work. I have updated the answer.